# How to convert DapperRow to Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dapper

I've a method that returns IEnumerable with Dapper Row.
[image]

But I'm trying to access the data without typecasting it to a particular class and I'm getting null value.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you are connecting to an SQL database

```
    public List<IDictionary<string, object>> DapperSelect(string connectionString, string query, object parameters)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var result = connection.Query(query, parameters).ToList();

            return result.Select(x => (IDictionary<string, object>)x).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I don't think that you should be converting your result to `IDictionary<string, string>` I don't think that has the desired effect you want, not every item in the dictionary is going to be a string, it could be bool, int, double, etc...

But if you insist, You could try to do something like

`result.Select(x => ((IDictionary<string, object>)x).ToDictionary(ks => ks.Key, vs => vs.ToString())).ToList();`

but I don't recommend it.

Better than all of that is that with dapper you can always strongly type the result returned from SQL, so instead of

`connection.Query(query, parameters).ToList();`

you would write

`connection.Query<YOURTYPE>(query, parameters).ToList();`

Comment: Is there any way to return List<IDictionary<string, string>>?

Comment: I don't think that has the desired effect you want, not every item in the dictionary is going to be a string, it could be bool, int, double, etc... you could try to do something like result.Select(x => ((IDictionary<string, object>)x).ToDictionary(ks => ks.Key, vs => vs.ToString())).ToList(); but that's really awful. You can always strongly type the result returned from dapper as well, so instead of connection.Query(query, parameters).ToList(), you would write connection.Query<TYOURTYPE>(query, parameters).ToList()

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var foo = db.Query(
                        "MySp",
                        new { parameters },
                        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                    .ToDictionary(
                        row => (int) row.Id,
                        row => (string) row.Name);
```

With row. being the names of the columns and foo being of type Dictionary .